# Printing RTF/HTML Files with Node.js

Tags: java, c#, node.js, printing, electron

I have the following problem:

I've created an electron app which prints out receipt with a thermal printer, however, the print quality really seems to suffer when using any other formats that .txt, .rtf or .html.

The module I've been using so far is [node-native-printer](https://github.com/MatteoMeil/node-native-printer) and although html is listed as a supported file type, it only prints out the unrendered html text.

I've also tried [JTextComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtext.html) but I could not get it to work with RTF or HTML. 
I am not familiar with C# so I do not know how I could play around with node-native-printer's .cs files to get it to work.

Also ideally there should not be any dialog popping up when printing and most importantly no extra user input required.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: In the past I have used rtf2pdf and html2pdf and then sent the pdf to the printer

Comment: This, unfortunately, leads to a very bad quality. My printer somehow doesn't like PDF files or any other than the ones I've mentioned above

Comment: What thermal printer are you using?

Comment: You would need to use a concrete subclass of JTextComponent.  The class you should be using is [JEditorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html).

Comment: @EdneyHolder It's called Maxatec SEWOO Elite #1, pretty unknown one I guess

Comment: @VGR Could you elaborate how I'd use a file as an input for JEditorPane to make it work? And do you know if it also renders the style attributes of the html file?